# Calculate entropy from binary bit string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

Want to calculate the entropy of binary string.

But for the different binary strings getting same results. so is it correct or not.

Data Set is like:

```
import math

#df :
A  B  C  D  Result
----------------------
x  x  x  x  111100100
x  x  x  x  110100100
x  x  x  x  111101111
x  x  x  x  100100100
.
.
.

Df1 = {'Result':[111100100, 110100100, 111101111, 100100100, 110100100, 111100111, 111101110],
```

For calculate entropy but for different string getting the same result.

```
def entropy(string):
        "Calculates the Shannon entropy of a string"

        # get probability of chars in string
        prob = [ float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dict.fromkeys(list(string)) ]

        # calculate the entropy
        entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in prob ])

        return entropy

df['entropy'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: entropy(x))
```

After run this code getting entropy result like this:

```
A  B  C  D  Result        entropy 
------------------------------------
x  x  x  x  111100100     0.991076
x  x  x  x  110100100     0.991076
x  x  x  x  111101111     0.503258
x  x  x  x  100100100     0.918296
.
.
.
```

Getting same entropy score for different binary strings.
Is it correct or not? dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

to understand go step by step:

`prob` of first string gives `[5, 4]`, and of second: `[4, 5]`. once you apply entropy, you take `sum`, it is indifferent if it takes 5 first and then 4 or vice versa.